# Construct a graph from a set of degrees

Tags: graph-theory

The question is:

Given the natural numbers $d_1 < d_2 < ... < d_k$, show that a graph $G$ with $d_k + 1$ nodes exist such that the set $\{d_1, d_2, ..., d_k\}$ represents the set of degrees of $G$.

The simple way to construct a graph from a given degree sequence is to use the Havel–Hakimi algorithm but in this case the degree sequence is potentially not specified for all nodes.
For example the set $\{6,5,2\}$ could result in multiple degree sequences for a graph with 7 nodes, e.g. $\{6,6,5,5,5,5,2\}$ or $\{6,5,5,5,5,2,2\}$ some of which are graphical and some others are not.
I was thinking as well about using the Erdös-Gallai theorem to see if that gives any hint about how to show that such a graph $G$ exists.

How would one prove that?

Comment: There's a theorem that says which degree sequences are graphical, so all you have to do is show that any set with max element $d$ can be turned into a graphical sequence of length $d+1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Right, I guess the theorem you mean is Erdös-gallai theorem?

Comment: I guess I can prove it with induction by assuming I can create a graph for a set $S$ of degrees $\{d_1, d_2, ..., d_k\}$ (the base case for a set with 1 element is easy) where $d_k$ is the max degree. Then use the theorem that is used in Havel–Hakimi algorithm to conclude that there must be also a set $S'$ $\{d_1, ..., d_{k-d_{k+1}}+1,..., d_{k-1}+1, d_k+1, d_{k+1}\}$ with the new max degree $d_{k+1}$. With that I should be able to conclude that I can always construct a graph for a set of degrees.